# ASP.NET MVC SSL too many redirects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl, https, web-config

I have a problem with my site. When I try to open it with "www." at the beginning of the address I get TOO MANY REDIRECTS 310 error. The problem started when I installed SSL certificate on my server and added `[RequireHttps]` at the top of my Home Controller (I have to use it here, because the log in form is in the master page). When I access my site without "www." everything is OK. The problem occurs in all browsers I have (FF, Chrome, IE, Opera).
In Opera I can see how the redirects go: it switches from http to https, but I have no idea why it gets back from https to http.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the configuration of the server at our hosting provider.